# Having problem with uploading multiple files in one request using dropzone

Tags: php, mysql, database, dropzone.js, dropzone

Am trying to update user image database column using dropzone plugin in one request but when i set **uploadMultiple** to true is not working no image move to folder neither database. But when i set it to false only last image name move to user image column but all images move to folder.

Thanks in advance

Here is my code

```
 Dropzone.options.mydropzone =
  {
      autoProcessQueue: false,
     addRemoveLinks: true,
      dictMaxFilesExceeded: "Maximum upload limit reached",
       dictInvalidFileType: "upload only JPG/PNG/JPEG/GIF/BMP",
    acceptedFiles: '.png,.jpg,.jpeg,.gif,.bmp',
        parallelUploads: 10,
          // uploadMultiple: true,
     init: function ()
    {
      var submitButton = document.querySelector('#letupload');
       myDropzone = this;


        submitButton.addEventListener("click", function(){
           myDropzone.processQueue();
        });


       this.on("complete", function(){
      if (this.getQueuedFiles().length == 0 && this.getUploadingFiles().length == 0) 
      {
        var _this = this;
        _this.removeAllFiles();
      }
      //console.log(this.getUploadingFiles());
    });

    },

  };
```

**Server Side**

```
if (!empty($_FILES)) {

  $temp_file = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
  $targetDir = '../../user_images/';
  $filename = rand().$_FILES['file']['name'];
  $targetFile = $targetDir.$filename;


 if (move_uploaded_file($temp_file, $targetFile)) {

      $sql="UPDATE img SET Image='$filename' WHERE User_id = '$memberid' ";//
if(!$qsql=mysqli_query($con,$sql))
{
  echo mysqli_error($con);
}

  } 


}
```

**After follow Mohammed link every images to to destination folder but only last image save into that database Below is my new server side code**

```
if (!empty($_FILES)) {


foreach($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'] as $key => $value) {
        $temp_file = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'][$key];
        $targetDir = '../../user_images/';
        $filename = rand().$_FILES['file']['name'][$key];
        $targetFile =  $targetDir.$filename;

        if (move_uploaded_file($temp_file,$targetFile)) {
         $sql="UPDATE img SET Image='$filename' WHERE User_id = '$memberid' ";//
        if(!$qsql=mysqli_query($con,$sql))
        {
          echo mysqli_error($con);
        }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: do you have any error ?

Comment: I don't get any errror

Comment: take a look here : https://gist.github.com/kreativan/83febc214d923eea34cc6f557e89f26c

Comment: Thanks **@MohammedYassineCHABLI** it working now all images move to destination folder but only one image name insert it to database

Comment: update your answser with the new code please to see where is the problem

Comment: All 4 images move to destination folder but only last image save into database, I want to save the image into database as follow: Image1.png,image2.png,image3.png,image4.png

Comment: why you are using update ? i think you need to INSERT instead

Comment: The user data already in the database, so I only want to update

Comment: yes i know , but if i really get what you are trying to do is fr example : user 1 can upload many image , so in the img table , you will have many row as img with the same  User_id , is that true ?

Comment: I have one table called img and I have column called image where user1 can upload only 4 images into one column but all images name will be separated by comma

Comment: can you show the schema of the two table please ?

Comment: Cool , i see where is the problem  , in fact , in each iteration , you udate with the last value , so that normal

Comment: Am in the mosque right now, but I think it's simple things that you can understand, I just want to convert all images name into array format something like img1.png,img2.png,img3.png,img.png  all these will be updated into image column

Comment: check  my answer .

Answer (score 1):

You are updating at each iteration , so the value at the end of script will be the name of the last image uploaded , so there is a way to solve this issue trying this  snippet of code :

- Insert into an array (i nammed id $images) the file name of uploaded
  files.
- convert array into spring separated by comma , using implode
  function .(i used the same variable $images).
- update the row with images name .

*Code example :*

```
if (!empty($_FILES)) {
   $images=array[];
  foreach($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'] as $key => $value) {
      $temp_file = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'][$key];
      $targetDir = '../../user_images/';
      $filename = rand().$_FILES['file']['name'][$key];
      $targetFile =  $targetDir.$filename;
      if (move_uploaded_file($temp_file,$targetFile)) {
         $images[]= $filename;
      }
  }
  $images = implode(',',$images);
  $sql="UPDATE img SET Image='$images' WHERE User_id = '$memberid' ";//
  if(!$qsql=mysqli_query($con,$sql)){
     echo mysqli_error($con);
  }

}
```

Hope this help you .

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Mohammed after I try your code, the problem of saving images name into database still persist, I now discover that you declare empty array inside the **foreach** so below is the working code

Dropzone Js

```
  Dropzone.options.mydropzone =
  {

    autoProcessQueue: false,
     addRemoveLinks: true,
      dictMaxFilesExceeded: "Maximum upload limit reached",
       dictInvalidFileType: "upload only JPG/PNG/JPEG/GIF/BMP",
    acceptedFiles: '.png,.jpg,.jpeg,.gif,.bmp',
        parallelUploads: 10,
          uploadMultiple: true,
     init: function ()
    {
      var submitButton = document.querySelector('#letupload');
       myDropzone = this;


        submitButton.addEventListener("click", function(){
           myDropzone.processQueue();
        });

      this.on("complete", function(file, response){
      if (this.getQueuedFiles().length == 0 && this.getUploadingFiles().length == 0) 
      {
        var _this = this;
        _this.removeAllFiles();
      }
      console.log(this.getUploadingFiles());
    });

    },


  };
```

Server Side

```
if (!empty($_FILES)) {

$empty_img_arr=array();
foreach($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'] as $key => $value) {
      $temp_file = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'][$key];
      $targetDir = '../../user_images/';
      $filename = rand().$_FILES['file']['name'][$key];
      $targetFile =  $targetDir.$filename;

      if (move_uploaded_file($temp_file,$targetFile)) {


       $empty_img_arr[]= $filename;

       $image = implode(',',$empty_img_arr);
    $sql="UPDATE img SET Image='$image' WHERE User_id = '$memberid' ";//
      if(!$qsql=mysqli_query($con,$sql))
      {
        echo mysqli_error($con);
      }

      }
  }

}
```

Thanks so much really appreciate